# Adjusting of php.ini

Tags: php

I know that it is possible to set parameters in php.ini like this:

```
error_log = "%sprogdir%/userdata/logs/%phpdriver%_error.log"
```

How can I properly run php using command line and set these parameters? Similarly:

```
php -c path/to/php/ini [here something like this: %sprogdir%=path1 %phpdriver%=path2]
```

Comment: I want to run php like this: php -c path/to/php/ini [here something like this: %sprogdir%=path1 %phpdriver%=path2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to be able to `export` a parameter to environment variables using PHP? If so, the `exec` command may be what you're looking for: [PHP: exec - Manual](http://php.net/function.exec).

You'd execute something similar to this I believe:

```
<?php
    echo exec('export phpdriver=value');
?>
```

---

EDIT: Due to misunderstanding of the question.

To correctly answer the question, we are going to create a script to set some environment variables before executing some PHP from the command line.

Here is our example shell - php_runner.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export progsdir=$1
export phpdriver=$2
php -c path/to/php/ini
```

Once this is created (remember to set correct permissions as well), we can execute it from command line as such:

```
/path/to/php_runner.sh path1 path2
```

Comment: For example: my php.ini contains line: error_log = "%sprogdir%/userdata/logs/%phpdriver%_error.log". I want to run php using command line: php -c path/to/php/ini [here something like this: %sprogdir%=path1 %phpdriver%=path2]

Comment: You could create a script which takes in the paths as parameters. The script would set the environment variables then execute the PHP.

Comment: could you show me a small example?

Comment: @see613 Please have a look at the update to the answer! I have edited it to address the example you requested.